# Openlayers map with dynamic markup

Tags: javascript

I have an open layers view that displays the numbers of reports for each country.

Can i display it other way for instance with dynamic circles markups : 
3 reports : small circles , 50 reports : medium circles etc ...

example:
http://reliefweb.int/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by passing a context function in Javascript that replaces the $-placeholders in your style object. I gave an example in [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/33465/633). The linked answer only changes the icon based on term rather than changing the marker size, but the principle's the same. Let me know if I can be of more help.

**Edit:** Sorry, I hadn't looked at your example when answering. That map doesn't involve clustering, so I think you can do it purely via the GUI. First you need to get the number as a field in Views and then use the appropriate placeholder (which you can see when you preview the data overlay display of the view) in the `pointRadius` field of the map's style.

**Details**

1. Make sure that the report count is a field in the *OpenLayers Data Overlay* display of your view.
2. Look at the preview of this display and note down the placeholder for the field - something like `${field_report_count}`.
3. Go to *Structure* -> *OpenLayers* -> *Maps* and edit the appropriate map.
4. Go to *Layers & Styles*, scroll down to *OVERLAY LAYERS* and look for the line which starts with the name of your view (it should end with *- OpenLayers Data Overlay*). Note down the name of the style in the *STYLE* column.
5. Go to *Structure* -> *OpenLayers* -> *Styles* and edit the style you noted down from step 4.
6. Put the field name you noted down from step 2. in the fields `pointRadius` and `label`. (I've never used the `label` field but I assume it does what you want.) You can also change the `labelAllign`, `labelXOffset` and `labelYOffset` fields if you want.

Comment: Thanx for the answer , I don't want to change the markup , but just the radius , if you inspect the code of reliefweb.int , they are changing just the r="" attribute of circle markup :                                         <circle id="OpenLayers.Geometry.Point_103" r="13" ....></circle>

Comment: @sel_space I understood that, was hoping you could take the principle and extend: instead of modifying `externalGraphic` you want to modify `pointRadius`.

Comment: Thank you for help , I'm looking for a simple solution because I don't have good level with javascript , I've juste looked at the code of managingnews (drupal distribution) , they are doing it with a small code

Comment: Also , I don't see the relation between the point and it's popup because the count appear in popup

Comment: @sel_space I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you , but this is not working , after the following steps it gives me r="1" for all circles